# Forecasting 5 Day Sales

Tags: forecasting, arima

I have daily sales data between 2013-02-18 to 2017-02-12 that has only 4 days of data missing (all the Xmases on the 25th of each year). These holidays have a sale volume of zero. **My purpose is to understand how to staff my store for the upcoming week by short-term predicting my sales for the next 5-7 days worth of data.**

I start by setting up this data as a time series:

```
ts <- ts(mydata, frequency = 365)
```

and then an initial analysis through a decomposition:

[image: Decomposition of daily data between 2013-02-18 to 2017-02-12]

This seems to show I have a declining sales trend, but there is some seasonality, if I'm not mistaken. So, to start my forecast implementation, I  fit an arima model for the first two years worth of data by doing:

```
fit <- auto.arima(ts[1:730], stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE)

Series: ts[1:730] 
ARIMA(4,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4      ma1
      0.3638  -0.2290  -0.1451  -0.2075  -0.8958
s.e.  0.0413   0.0388   0.0388   0.0398   0.0241

sigma^2 estimated as 15424930:  log likelihood=-7068.67
AIC=14149.33   AICc=14149.45   BIC=14176.88
```

This model doesn't seem right to me, because it does not include any seasonality. I know I have enough data. Rob Hyndman's blog said to try using `ets` which also showed no seasonality. What am I not understanding about this data series or the forecasting methodology?

Answer (score 0):

I've re-asked this question more appropriately in the stats exchange forums. Could someone please close this question here in stackexchange for me?

The questions is now here.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295012/forecast-5-7-day-sales